# Statistical methods for assigning weights based on rank differences?

Tags: ranking, mean, methodology, weights

I have encountered methodological problem in my pursuit of my master's degree, and I hope you can help! I know exactly what I want to do, but I do not know which statistical area this is related to. I have created the following picture depiction, of what my goal is:

[image]

From the picture above, each person has a feature attached to him/her. Either one of these three features, is a composite measure based on several variables. If person 0 is the "base/target" person, and I want to calculate how different each subjects are, I calculate the absolute rank difference.

Based on these rank differences, it becomes evident that person 3 is closest (in terms of features) to person 0. Now, what I want to know from this - is how to assign weights based on these rank differences. The goal is to take the known people (person 1, 2, 3 and 4) and estimate a Z value for person 0, based on some weighting procedure of the rank differences (or maybe the "strength/importance" of each feature?).

Do you have any recommendations, as to what methods I can look into? Furthermore, if I want to see which variables in the composite scores, that are most important for making the features x1, x2 and x3, what could I do? I was thinking of a regression, but there might be issues with multicollinearity.